# Variable shows undefined in AngularJS, inspite of value being available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to send some form data in a JSON to server, but due to some reason error pops up in the console saying

> ReferenceError: formatdata is not defined
>       at m.$scope.submit (Index.js:59)

What i have been trying to do is

```
var formdata = new Object();
var packet = new Object();
console.log($scope.id+' '+$scope.bsName+' '+$scope.age); //succesfull
formdata.toddlerId = $scope.id;
formdata.toddlerName = $scope.name;
formdata.bsName = $scope.bsName;
formdata.toddlerAge = $scope.age;
JSON.stringify(formatdata); //shows error here
console.log(formatdata.toddlerId);
packet.DecoyToddler = JSON.stringify(formatdata);
packet.task = 'register';
console.log(JSON.stringify(packet));
```

I did somethin like this previously

```
var action = new Object();
action.task = 'reg';
$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'Controller',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: JSON.stringify(action), //no error here
    contentType : 'application/json',
    mimeType : 'application/json',
}).then(function(response){
var list = response.data;
```

I am unable to understand why code-segment 2 works and 1 doesn't. I am new to Javascript and AngularJs, so i apologize if its too silly mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `formdata` instead of `formatdata`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo there,

it should be,

`JSON.stringify(formdata);`